# How Do I Change The Appended Input Value?

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 input values, both with a 30 integer max. Their values are added together and attached to the "results" class.

However, I want to change the value of an input to "1" when the value is less than 5, with the original value remaining in the input box, and the new value attached to ".results", while still maintaining the addition factor with ".results".

HTML

```
<div class="section">
    <input type="number" class="chicken" min="0" max="30"/>
    <input type="number" class="turkey" min="0" max="30"/>
</div>

<p class="results"></p>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on("keyup", "input", function() {
    var chicken = parseInt($('.chicken').val(), 10);
    var turkey = parseInt($('.turkey').val(), 10);
    if (chicken < 5) {
        $(sum).val(2);
    }
    $("input").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".results").html(sum);    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check against values when you loop through elements.
If any of them is less than `5`, then you add `1` to `sum` value instead of real value. Otherwise you use real values.

```js
 $(document).on("keyup", "input", function() { 
        var sum = 0;
        var chicken = parseInt($('.chicken').val(), 10);
        var turkey = parseInt($('.turkey').val(), 10);
         $("input").each(function(){
         if($(this).val() < 5)
         { 
            sum === 1 ? sum : sum++;
         }
         else
         {
            sum += +$(this).val();
         }
        });
        $(".results").html(sum);    
    });
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="section">
        <input type="number" class="chicken" min="0" max="30"/>
        <input type="number" class="turkey" min="0" max="30"/>
    </div>

    <p class="results"></p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is great except when I add a "1" (or anything for that matter), the result is one more than needed. So adding just a "1" to one box results in "2" -- it should be "1".

Comment: Awesome -- thanks a bunch, @Giulio! And if I wanted to change the "1" to a "2" for an else if statement?

Comment: @Weebs if you want value to be "2' and not "1":                                                         if($(this).val() < 5)
         { 
            sum === 2 ? sum : sum += 2;
         }

Comment: Thanks, @Giulio! I really appreciate your help with this!